# Customize error message with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, error-handling

I'm using the simple_form gem. I want to customize the error message displayed when a user fails validations. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: do you want to customise the error message or the style of error message disolayed?

Comment: i initially meant the content of error message, but I'd also be interested in customizing the style as well. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily change the default error message comes in the translation file, which is found in `config/locales/simple_form.en.yml`.

In the specific initializer, `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` you can overrule the default options how the html is generated.

Hope this helps.

For completeness, I would like to add that formtastic is an easier choice to start with, because it has a default layout. I like simple_form a lot, but it does not offer any formatting out of the box, but that is their intention. With Formtastic it is very hard (impossible) to change the generated html, and with simple_form can you can completely mold the generated html to your liking. This is especially useful if you have a designer, and the forms you generate have to generate the same html. So if you are getting started, formtastic will give you nicer-looking results quicker. Also note that it is quite easy to switch, because the syntax is almost identical.

Comment: what's the syntax for changing the default error messages in `simple_form.en.yml`? what if you have two validations for an attribute, like `:presence => true` and `:format => ...`? how would you provide different messages for each?

Comment: The standard validation messages has nothing to do with simple_form, but is standard ActiveRecord. You either explicitly declare the message in the validation, or you can check https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n where the standard messages are defined (and how to overwrite them).

Comment: Is there a way to configure simple_form to link labels and error messages to the default activerecord i18n yaml?

Comment: Your question is not enitrely clear, please ask it in a separate question; btw i have also answered a question how to use i18n for labels in simple-form, their documentation on github covers this very well imho.

Answer (score 18):

1. You can declare the content of the
   error message in your model:

   ```
   validates_length_of :name, :minimum => 5, :message => "blah blah blah"
   ```
2. You can set `id` or `class` for your
   error tag:

   ```
   <%= f.input :name, :error_html => { :id => "name_error"} %>
   ```

   Then you can use CSS for the styling.
3. And you can use

   ```
   <%= f.error :name, :id => "name_error" %>
   ```

   and you'll get

   ```
   <span class="error" id="name_error">is too short (minimum is 5 characters)</span>
   ```

Answer (score 7):

I dont know if it is any different for simple_form gem.

For content of error messages to be changed, you can use the `:message` attribute in the model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, {:presence => true, :message => "is not filled up."}
end
```

Now the validation message will be `Email is not filled up`. If you want the field name also to be changed(`Email` to `E-mail address` something like that ), the approach now is to define it in `locales.rb` file like this

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "E-mail address"
```

See [link](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) for details on `locales`. Another approach is to define in the model, humanized attributes like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, {:presence => true, :message => "is not filled up."}
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :email => "E-mail address",
    ...(other fields and their humanized names)
    ...
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

For customizing style of validation message we will have to edit the style for 
`#errorExplanation` and `.fieldWithErrors`,in the `scaffold.css` stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution explained [here](https://www.eltacolab.com/coding/rails-how-to-change-error-messages-in-simple-form) that wasn't mentioned in the answers. You can directly override the error messages from the views, in the form itself. For example:

```
<%= f.input :last_name,
               placeholder: 'last_name',
               error: 'This is a custom error message',
               required: true,
               class: 'form-field',
               autofocus: true,
               input_html: { autocomplete: "last_name" } %>
```

It is however not advised as it is not DRY, you would need to override it in every field.